# Spring boot and aws cognito : unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-cognito

I am trying to do a very basic POC with spring boot 3.1 and aws cognito.
My aim is when I hit http:localhost:8080 then it should redirect to cognito login page.

Any help or guidance will be truly appreciated.

Below are the application files:

this is my application.yml

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          cognito:
            client-id: kjdsaksdkjahdjkahdkjdaskke
            client-secret: b8ilfhsfdklsdfsflshflkdshflsdhfsldfhsldfhflkhsdbfeu
        provider:
          cognito:
            issuer-uri: https://cognito-idp.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/ap-south-1_abcdefgh
```

This is my application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebSecurity
public class CongnitoDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CongnitoDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.congnito.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>com-congnito-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>congnito demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot and cognito</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest</builder>
                    </image>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Exception I getting:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.9+8\bin\java.exe" -javaagent:C:\ideaIC-

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.3)

2024-01-14T14:23:39.711+05:30  INFO 15032 --- [           main] 
..
..
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://cognito-idp.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/ap-south-1_abcdefgh/.well-known/openid-configuration": PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
....
....
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:148) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:129) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434) ~[na:na]
    ... 164 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is what I tried to fix the error:

```
Open an HTTPS connection to the URL (i.e https://www.example.com/, https://saas.whitesourcesoftware.com/ in the browser

1. Press F12 to access the browser’s Developer Tools

2. Go to the ‘Security’ tab

3.Click ‘View certificate’

4. In the Certificate details window, go to the ‘Details’ tab

5. Click ‘Export’

6. Make sure the file format is: ‘Base64-encoded ASCII, single certificate (*.pem, *.crt)’

7. Name the file: Windows: ‘whitesourcesoftware.com.crt’ 

I have used 'https://cognito-idp.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com' also in place of https://www.example.com/ but same result its showing
```

Comment: I have this use case working with Spring BOOT 2.x. It works perfectly. Spring Bopot 2.x supports public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter , which is used to hook in a Spring Boot app with Cognito. I will post link soon.

Comment: See  - https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/usecases/creating_amazon_cognito_app

Comment: Thanks @smac2020 for creating such an easy to follow steps, now its showing  cognito login page for me.